# Google Maps for Flash throws RTE in new Polyline()

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps, actionscript, flex4, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting the following error with Google Maps API:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at com.google.maps.overlays::Polyline()
```

[image]

Specifying the second constructor parameter does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that any object including `Polylne` can be created only when map is initializated.

Comment: That's so annoying. As you state, above, this is also the case for creating Markers...  This makes testing tricky. I have an actionscript class that creates markers but to test it, I have to mess around with a Map... and my map exists inside of an MXML file. I wasted a couple hours debugging a test with no flaws before finding this post :/